# Can I create custom horizontal tables with AG-Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

What I need is a table with the following format:

[image]

However, I haven't seen been able to see this in their [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/).

I'm currently doing it by applying some "Table styling" to a form, but I'd rather using AG-Grid.

Comment: What have you tried?  And how is it not working?  Please could you add some code or a StackBlitz so we can help

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know where to start because in the documentation you have "columnDefs" and "rowData" which represent the properties and the values for each row respectively. However, what I'd need is a "firstColumnDef" and "secondColumnData", being each row a new property-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Enterprise licence, you can use the pivot tables

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/pivoting/

From the documentation, you just have to add "pivot: true" to the column definitions

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    /* other grid options ... */>
</ag-grid-angular>

this.columnDefs = [
    { field: "country", pivot: true },
    { field: "sport", pivot: true }
];
```

If you don't have an Enterprise licence then it will be more of a struggle